# How are past alarms delivered by the AlarmManager?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I've got a question about setting alarms in the AlarmManager. I found something in the docs I didn't understand (see below). I'd like to set 10 alarms which trigger the ringer mode alternately silent and normal, all with a different trigger time. Now the device goes asleep, and becomes active again after all 10 alarms are outdated. Does the AlarmManager then immediately broadcast an alarm? Would it be only the 10th (what about the ringer mode)?

> Alarm intents are delivered with a
>   data extra of type int called
>   Intent.EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT that
>   indicates how many past alarm events
>   have been accumulated into this intent
>   broadcast. Recurring alarms that have
>   gone undelivered because the phone was
>   asleep may have a count greater than
>   one when delivered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, when scheduling an alarm with an alarm manager, you have to provide a PendingIntent instance.

There are two Types of alarms ones that will wake up and do work even if the phone is asleep or locked and ones that will not.

Also, If you were to schedule 10 things at one time The AlarmManager will replace the existing Scheduled Pending intent with the new one, unless you were giving it different intent actions.  When I use Alarms I have always used a sqlite database to queue up jobs that I wanted to execute on some schedule.  From there I would schedule one alarm at a time, because they all executed the same Intent when the buzzer went ding.

The EXTRA_ALARM_COUNT extra would come into play if you had a reoccurring alarm scheduled and it went off multiple times when the users device was asleep.  When the phone wakes up it will replay anything that it has queued up in the past.  In this case your pending intent will fire off and have the value of how many times your Alarm was skipped because it was constructed with RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME as the type when calling the set method.

Here is a sample of how I usually interact with the AlarmManger

```
protected void scheduleNext(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = getAlarmManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyIntent.ACTION_DO_WORK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0); 

    String where = Queue.SCHEDULED_DATE + "= (select min(" + Queue.SCHEDULED_DATE + ") from queue where " + Queue.COMPLETED_DATE + " is null)";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Queue.CONTENT_URI, Queue.PROJECTION, where, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Queue._ID));
        long when = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Queue.SCHEDULED_DATE));
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pendingIntent);
    }   

    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. What I don't understand is why PendingIntents are overwritten. Isn't it possible to schedule two PendingIntents which do the same at a different time?

Comment: And another question: "...When the phone wakes up it will replay anything that it has queued up in the past. In this case your pending intent will fire off..." - do you mean only the last PendingIntent?

Comment: Yep the AlarmManager will send the PendingIntent the next time the device wakes up, if the alarm went off while the device was sleeping.

Comment: I had the same frustrations when trying to queue up a bunch of things that I wanted to trigger at different times.  Thats why I started to implement my internal queue.

Comment: Alright, just one last thing - could you explain what exactly recurrent alarms are, is it that they don't have different intent actions? Perhaps that could be a solution to this problem... :)

Comment: Ok.. I read that recurrent alarm need a fixed interval. So your way to schedule the same intents several times seems to be a solution. But when do you call your scheduleNext()... it's really a bit frustrating...

Comment: I have a service that has the responsibility of scheduling the alarm. When my action to do work completes, it starts the service to schedule next.  So lets say that I have five things that need to get done all at different times.  My do work service will do any job that has a scheduled time in the past, and that has not been completed.  While executing all past jobs the do work service updates the queue with a completed date/time.  Once all jobs have been completed.  The do work service starts the schedule next service, setting the alarm for the next upcoming time that work needs to be done.

Comment: Jep, that sounds good. I thought of something like that.. to schedule a next alarm as soon as the last reaction has completed. I'll try it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One thing that is most unknown (mainly because the Android documentation tells that its ["not used at the moment"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)) is that the PendingIntent will not be reused if the requestCode differs. So instead create the PI with an request code of 0:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

You could implement a counter and do someting like:

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, counter, intent, 0);
```

I know that this will work for SMS delivered/sent notifications PendingIntents, where you have the same problem: If the PendingIntent is reused and you have more than 1 outstanding notification, you will not know for which SMS it was. 
But chances are good that this will also work for outstanding alarm PendingIntent.

Hope this helps.